How to perform parallel addition using AVX with carry (overflow) fed back into the same element (PE checksum)?
I want to perform eight parallel adds of 16bit values using AVX SIMD. Addition with overflow is required, i.e. 'add with carry' like it is performed with the old "adc" x86 mnemonic.
I implemented 50 percent of the AVX solution myself, the carry handling, also performed by AVX instructions, is missing. My current solution:
typedef union _uint16vec uint16vec, *uint16vec_ptr;

union  __attribute__((aligned(16))) _uint16vec
{
  __m128i             x;
  uint16_t            y[8];
};

__m128i parallel_add_with_carry ( __m128i n1, __m128i n2 )
{
  volatile uint16vec  res, stupid_carry;
  uint32_t            i;

  stupid_carry.x = n1; /* load 8x uint16_t for carry adjustment below */

  __asm__
  (
    "movdqa %1, %%xmm0             \n\t"
    "movdqa %2, %%xmm1             \n\t"
    "vpaddw %%xmm0, %%xmm1, %%xmm0 \n\t"
    "movdqa %%xmm0, %0             \n\t"
    : "=m" (res.x)                      /* output */
    : "m" (n1), "m" (n2)                /* inputs */
    : "xmm0", "xmm1"                    /* GCC, please clobber XMM0 and XMM1 */
  );

  /* if each of the eight uint16_t in the result is lesser than
   * the previous value, then we have the overflow situation...
   */
  for (i=0;i<8;i++)
    res.y[i] += (res.y[i] < stupid_carry.y[i]) ? 1 : 0;

  return res.x;
}

void test ( void )
{
  uint16vec   v1 = {0}, v2 = {0}, res;

  v1.y[0] = 0x000A; v2.y[0] = 0x0014; /* 10+20 = 30 (0x001E), no overflow */
  v1.y[1] = 0xFFF0; v2.y[1] = 0x0013; /* 0xFFF0 + 0x0013 = 0x0003 -> overflow -> 0x0004 */

  res.x = parallel_add_with_carry(v1.x, v2.x);

  fprintf(stdout,"%04X | %04X\n", res.y[0], res.y[1]);
}

The GCC-emitted object code of the function's epilogue is terrible (even with -O3). My question is if there is a better AVX-supported solution for the 'add with carry' problem?

May the 'vpcmp<CC>uw' compare instruction with <CC>=LT (lesser than) help?
How can I use these 'K' (mask) registers (K0..K7) for that?

My idea was to provide a 128bit vector { 0x0001,0x0001,...,0x0001} as a 128bit temporary variable adding this (the carry vector) to the eight uint16_t's if and only if the preceding compare operation resulted in a 'lesser than' for specific uint16_t in the 128bit vector.
I browsed the Intel documentation and found nice add instructions that just copy source parts of the vector if a condition is met.
Support with this 'AVX thing' is highly appreciated. Thanks.

vpcmpuw is AVX-512.  AVX2 only has signed integer compares, although it has unsigned min/max and saturating subtract, which you might be able to do something with.  You tagged this AVX2, are you also looking for a version of this that supports x86-64-v3 (AVX2 but not AVX-512)?

Why inline asm?  The way you're writing it, with memory input and output operands, is not efficient.  x86 SIMD instructions allow a memory source operand.  And you're not getting any benefit from using the legacy-SSE encoding of movdqa; if you wanted to save code-size by avoiding the VEX encoding, use movaps.  But probably better to use vmovdqa, although with 128-bit vectors you won't get SSE/AVX transition stalls as long as the upper halves of the YMM/ZMM regs are clean (vzeroupper)

Your existing code looks like it increments the element of res by 1 if there was carry-out.  That is very weird; the carry-out has a place-value of 2^16, but you're feeding it back in to the bottom of the same element, place value 2^0.  Normally you'd want to conditionally increment another vector if you're doing eight parallel 32-bit counters where each one is split into two 16-bit halves.

Peter, thank you very much for your input. I am going to revise this stuff. The basic idea was/is to perform eight 16bit additions in parallel. Then, comparing to the intermediate result before the current add, find out which of the eight 16bit values had an overflow, correcting only these 16bit values by adding another one.

And yes, I would like to use all kinds of AVX/AVX-512 in order to get this optimized. This code is used in the checksum calculation of PE executables, which require the addition of all 16bit words (with carry). The current version performs the job well but is still suboptimal...

With this 16-bit checksum (feeding carry-out back into carry-in), is addition still associative?  I think so, otherwise you couldn't vectorize it in the first place.  You could shorten critical-path latency by adding the carry-out into a different vector, only adding it back into the primary accumulator at the end.

Do you mean you have all of AVX1/2/512 available, and you want one version that's as fast as possible regardless of whether that means using AVX2 or AVX-512?  Or do you mean you also want a version that only uses AVX2, and another version that only uses AVX1, as well as a version that uses AVX-512BW?

@Devvy Note that in your code you're not propagating the carry correctly, since adding the carry may also overflow, and this overflow must be accounted for in the higher elements.

@AndreySemashev: Double overflow isn't possible.  Consider 8-bit with the largest possible inputs: 0xFF + 0xFF is 0xFE with a carry-out of 1.  Adding it back into the bottom we get 0xFF without overflow.  This is a checksum, not bigint addition, so carry propagation is not into a different element.

@PeterCordes I originally thought the OP wanted to implement the usual add-with-carry, meaning that the carry propagates to the next, more significant element of the sum. Without propagation, yes, double overflow can't happen.

One simple idea is to leverage unsigned saturation, which makes the results of the addition different from the overflowing addition when overflow happens.
__m128i parallel_add_with_carry(__m128i n1, __m128i n2)
{
    // Make an all-ones vector. This is virtually free and does not
    // consume an execution unit.
    const __m128i mm_all_ones = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(n1, n1);

    __m128i mm_sum = _mm_add_epi16(n1, n2);
    // Since there is no "not equal" comparison that produces
    // a vector mask, we compare for "equal" and get a negated
    // carry mask.
    __m128i mm_carry = _mm_cmpeq_epi16(_mm_adds_epu16(n1, n2), mm_sum);
    // Negate the mask, which turns elements that were 0 to -1 and vise versa
    mm_carry = _mm_xor_si128(mm_carry, mm_all_ones);
    // Add carry (i.e. subtract -1 or 0)
    mm_sum = _mm_sub_epi16(mm_sum, mm_carry);

    return mm_sum;
}

Godbolt
This implementation is compatible with SSE2 and later. Using AVX-512 and opmask registers is possible, but unlikely to be any faster. Here are some estimates (asm code generated by gcc 14.2 with -O3 -march=rocketlake):

Asm-based solution from Devvy's answer. Note that here I'm using the code as presented in the answer verbatim, with the unoptimal instruction encoding selection and passing arguments via stack.
The same AVX-512 implementation ported to intrinsics (Godbolt). This fixes the code generation inefficiencies in the asm version.
SSE2 implementation from this answer.

If you're processing moderate amounts of data that likely fit in cache, it may be beneficial to further optimize this code by unrolling the loop and using separate accumulators for the sum and carry, and only add them together at the end, when all data is processed. This improves instruction-level parallelism (ILP) as the separate accumulations form separate dependency chains and can happen in parallel, provided that there are enough arithmetic execution units in the CPU and the algorithm isn't bottlenecked elsewhere (e.g. by memory bandwidth).
__m128i parallel_add_with_carry_loop(const unsigned char* data, size_t size)
{
    __m128i mm_sum1 = _mm_setzero_si128(), mm_sum2 = _mm_setzero_si128();
    __m128i mm_carry1 = _mm_setzero_si128(), mm_carry2 = _mm_setzero_si128();
    const __m128i mm_all_ones = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(mm_sum1, mm_sum1);

    for (size_t i = 0u, n = size & (size_t)(-32); i < n; i += 32)
    {
        __m128i mm1 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(data + i));
        __m128i mm2 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i*)(data + i + 16));
        __m128i mm_new_sum1 = _mm_add_epi16(mm_sum1, mm1);
        __m128i mm_new_sum2 = _mm_add_epi16(mm_sum2, mm2);
        __m128i mm_neg_carry1 = _mm_cmpeq_epi16(
            _mm_adds_epu16(mm_sum1, mm1), mm_new_sum1);
        __m128i mm_neg_carry2 = _mm_cmpeq_epi16(
            _mm_adds_epu16(mm_sum2, mm2), mm_new_sum2);
        mm_sum1 = mm_new_sum1;
        mm_sum2 = mm_new_sum2;
        mm_carry1 = _mm_sub_epi16(mm_carry1,
            _mm_xor_si128(mm_neg_carry1, mm_all_ones));
        mm_carry2 = _mm_sub_epi16(mm_carry2,
            _mm_xor_si128(mm_neg_carry2, mm_all_ones));
    }

    // If size is not a multiple of 32, process the tail bytes here
    // ...

    // Combine the accumulated sum and carry. Note that adding sums
    // may overflow, and we need to account the carry from this addition.
    mm_sum1 = parallel_add_with_carry(mm_sum1, mm_sum2);
    mm_carry1 = _mm_add_epi16(mm_carry1, mm_carry2);
    mm_sum1 = _mm_add_epi16(mm_sum1, mm_carry1);

    return mm_sum1;
}


Since this is for a PE checksum (according to the comments), there shouldn't be a left shift, adding the carry out of an element to that same element is intended (and then you also don't need a loop since an end-around carry cannot generate another carry)

@user555045: And you can add into a separate vector accumulator for carries, I think, shortening critical-path latency when using this in a loop vs. a longer chain of operations to update a single vector before looking at the next chunk of source data.

If you were trying to implement 128-bit addition, you'd do it with two 64-bit elements just subtracting 0 or -1 unconditionally from the high half.  AVX includes vpcmpgtq so you could work around the lack of saturating math for other element sizes.  Of course, SIMD is not better than scalar on x86-64 for that; add/adc is more efficient than AVX shenanigans, unless you can use partial-word storage for your numbers so you can avoid carry-propagation on most operations, only renormalizing occasionally.  (Can long integer routines benefit from SSE?)

@user555045 Then I misunderstood the question. Thanks for pointing this out.

I've updated the answer to implement PE checksum rather than add-with-carry.

Can we avoid the _mm_andnot_si128 and just use _mm_sub_epi16?  Or is it not possible to directly get the 0 or -1 we'd need from pcmpeqw or pcmpgtw fed by one previous instruction?

@PeterCordes Yes, I applied your suggestion to use _mm_sub_epi16. Thanks. But I don't think there will be any meaningful performance difference, based on uica.uops.info simulation. It does reduce the code by 2 uops and a couple instructions, so there's that. The difference is only because the all-ones constant is easier to generate than a vector of 16-bit ones. You still need to negate the carry mask, so you trade pandn for pxor, which are equivalent.

If doing this across multiple vectors, we could accumulate the carry-outs inverted so we only have to negate them once.  (Or sub them from the main vector accumulator instead of add).  Later carry-outs would happen at different points, but the total is still x + (x/65536) I think.  Not usable in the API of the OP's wrapper function which does everything for one vector, but a stand-alone function is a distraction from optimizing a loop that inlines it.

@PeterCordes I'm not sure how you would accumulate negated carry. You need to accumulate the negated carry elements that are zeros, meaning you need to make those elements non-zero before accumulation one way or another. At this point, does it matter whether you accumulate them separately or straight into the final result? Using a separate accumulator is potentially better ILP, but I'm not sure it'll matter in practice.

I was thinking pcmpeqw / psubw carries, cmp_result and then add or sub the carries in once at the end.  So you don't need a negation for every pcmp.  Does that work?  I haven't fully through it through or tried it out.

And yeah, the ILP improvement from a separate accumulator should be a big deal; 4 cycle critical path latency for your version (parallel add and adds) vs. 1 cycle critical path latency so just bottlenecking on 3 or 4 vector ALU uops per clock (assuming the front-end is wide enough to get loads + loop overhead done), so 5/3 cycles per vector down from 4, for large enough input blocks that out-of-order exec can't overlap it much with surrounding code, but where mem bandwidth isn't a bottleneck, so maybe already hot in L2 cache.

@PeterCordes I don't think that works, if I understand it correctly. Again, you need to increment the result if there was overflow (i.e. the negated carry/pcmpeqw result is zero). You must not modify the sum if there was no overflow. For example, n1 = 0xFFFF, n2 = 1, intermediate sum = n1 + n2 = 0, negated carry = 0, final sum = sum + (negated carry == 0) = 0 + 1 = 1. Example 2: n1 = 1, n2 = 1, intermediate sum = 2, negated carry = 0xFFFF, final sum = 2.

@PeterCordes I've added a version with separate accumulators to the answer. The bounding latency in this case is the carry accumulation, which should be the same as the latency of the version without the separate carry accumulator. I.e. you still need to calculate the mm_new_sum in order to accumulate the carry. Which means, the entire loop + the final add(sum, carry) should take about the same time as the one accumulator loop. Am I missing something?

@PeterCordes One optimization that could be useful would be to unroll the loop and use multiple sum and carry accumulators. That would break the dependency chain for each of the accumulators. But then there's no need to accumulate the sum and the carry separately - you could just as well unroll the one-accumulator version.

The parallel version has two separate 1-cycle loop-carried dependencies, one feeding the other with a chain a few cycles long.  So one has to be ahead of the other by a couple cycles, but crucially carry doesn't feed back into sum so throughput can still be 1/clock (or limited by ALU throughput).  Latency bounds and throughput bounds for processors for operations that must occur in sequence discusses a simpler example with two dep chains, one coupled to the other.

@PeterCordes Even if we disregard the latency is accumulating mm_sum (assuming that accumulator is running ahead of mm_carry), you still have _mm_adds_epu16+_mm_cmpeq_epi16+_mm_xor_si128+_mm_sub_epi16 = 4 cycles of latency to calculate mm_carry on every loop iteration. With one mm_sum accumulator, you have the same plus the _mm_add_epi16, so 5 cycles. However, e.g. with 2x unroll you're creating a second dependency chain and halve the total loop latency for each of the chains. This is a much larger gain than 5->4 cycles per iteration.

@AndreySemashev the next iteration can start before that cmp/xor/sub chain has ended, the add/cmp/xor of the next iteration don't depend on the result of the sub

@AndreySemashev: Did you read the linked answer in my last comment? It explains what user555.... summarized (and shows an ASCII-art diagram), that out-of-order exec can get started early on the next iteration of one chain so they don't need to run in lockstep.

Thank you very much for this great work and collaboration. You guys are awesome! A lot of people may benefit from this work also performing other SIMD stuff. I personally was not quite into this SIMD domain but learned a lot from you. Thanks again.

One more "stupid" question: What CPUID bit do I have to check for this SSE2 stuff?

@Devvy On 64-bit x86 you don't have to check anything since SSE2 is implicitly present on any 64-bit x86 CPU. On older 32-bit CPUs you can check bit 26 of edx returned by cpuid with eax=1. See Determine processor support for SSE2?.

@PeterCordes Yes, I read the answer, but I didn't realize that _mm_adds_epu16, _mm_cmpeq_epi16 and _mm_xor_si128 do not depend on the previous iteration of the carry accumulation loop and can be executed earlier. user555045's comment made that click. Thanks to you both.

Ok, good. :) Now that you see what I was saying, is there any way I could have stated it more clearly than "carry doesn't feed back into sum" and other parts of that earlier comment?  Or was it just one of those things where it took a different commenter and/or an hour away from it to make you look again at it and spot the mistake in your assumptions?  I've had that happen to me.

@PeterCordes I guess, it was just explicitly stating that those instructions don't depend on the previous iteration that made me go back and reevaluate the code. "carry doesn't feed back into sum" didn't make that obvious to me at the time. Maybe I didn't put enough thought in it.

I found the solution using AVX-512 instructions. The solution is the merging-masking functionality using the CPU's mask registers (named K0 through K7).
I have tested it on a server box with an AMD Epyc 7000 series (48 cores).
C source code with inline assembly
In the context of my initial source code:
    __m128i parallel_add_with_carry_simd ( __m128i n1, __m128i n2 )
    {
      static const uint16vec carry = { .y[0] = 0x0001,
                                       .y[1] = 0x0001,
                                       .y[2] = 0x0001,
                                       .y[3] = 0x0001,
                                       .y[4] = 0x0001,
                                       .y[5] = 0x0001,
                                       .y[6] = 0x0001,
                                       .y[7] = 0x0001 };
      uint16vec res;
    
      __asm__
      (
        "movdqa    %1    , %%xmm0                 \n\t"
        "movdqa    %2    , %%xmm1                 \n\t"
        "movdqa    %3    , %%xmm3                 \n\t"
        "movdqa    %%xmm0, %%xmm2                 \n\t"
        "vpaddw    %%xmm1, %%xmm0, %%xmm0         \n\t"
        "vpcmpltuw %%xmm2, %%xmm0, %%k1           \n\t"
        "vpaddw    %%xmm3, %%xmm0, %%xmm0 %{%%k1%}\n\t"
        "movdqa    %%xmm0, %0                     \n\t"
        : "=m" (res.x)
        : "m" (n1), "m" (n2), "m" (carry.x)
        : "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3"
      );
    
      return res.x;
    }

Essentially, you have to execute the sequence:

First addition of eight 16bit unsigned integers in a 128bit XMM register;
Execution of 'vpcmpuw' with condition code 'LT' (lesser than);
Second CONDITIONAL addition of a carry vector (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1).

This implements the old x86 'add with carry' mnemonic 'adc' on vectors of 16bit unsigned integers.
Walkthrough and technical background
The inline assembly loads the two vectors to be added with carry n1 and n2 into XMM0 and XMM1. The helper carry vector (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) gets loaded into XMM3.
We save the original vector n1 in XMM2 (for later comparison). The calculation of n1 + n2 is performed (no saturation!) according to:
    XMM0 := XMM0 (n1) + XMM1 (n2)

This intermediate result does not include the carries yet.
The role of vpcmpuw
The key is the comparison
    vpcmpltuw %%xmm2, %%xmm0, %%k1

meaning: Compare the intermediate result XMM0 with the original input n1 in XMM2. Use the condition code 'lesser than' (LT). Store the eight comparison results as separate bits in the mask register K1.
The second, conditional add operation
The second vpaddw instruction performs the job of 'carry correction' on the eight 16bit integers in XMM0:
     vpaddw %%xmm3, %%xmm0, %%xmm0 %{%%k1%}

This (weird) notation means: Add the carry vector (in XMM3) to the intermediate result (in XMM0) storing the overall result again in XMM0. Use the mode merging-masking (as opposite to zeroing-masking - see below) while adding.
The pseudo code of merging-masking is:
    FORALL eight 16bit integers in XMM0 DO
    IF   : bit in K1 is 1 
    THEN : add 0x0001 from the carry vector in XMM3 (XMM0 := XMM0 + XMM3)
    ELSE : just copy the current 16bit integer from src (XMM0) to dst (XMM0)

What is zeroing-masking?
An operation alternative to merging-masking is zeroing-masking. You would have to specify the inline assembly in this case as follows:
    vpaddw %%xmm3, %%xmm0, %%xmm0 %{%%k1%}%{z%}

If a bit in the K1 register is one, then the addition is performed. If it is a zero bit, then 0x0000 is stored in the destination (thus zeroing the current 16bit integer).
Credits
Eventually, I could solve it thanks to this post: stackoverflow, writemask in AVX-512

Looks like it would work, but it doesn't look efficient. After this gets inlined into the loop that calculates the total chechsum, there will still be some redundant moves (if you used intrinsics instead of inline asm, the compiler could do something about that, but not with inline asm). It also seems possible to do this with a less latency through the loop-carried dependency chain (still talking about the loop which is not shown here, but you will have to call this function from a loop).

Thank you for your input. Of course, I integrated this in an inline assembly section that performs the looping as part of the it (the jump label is 16 byte aligned), everything is as interleaved as I could manage it - to be honest, I do not know if this u/v pipeline stuff from 20 years ago still plays a role? The code works "like a charm" on the AMD Epyc 7000er at least.

The u/v thing is far behind us, we have out-of-order execution now so the exact interleaving is not as important as it was. Doing the whole loop in inline asm is fine I suppose. Still, the vpaddw/vpcmpltuw/vpaddw sequence has a latency of 6 cycles, I think (or maybe 5?) on Zen4, since the result is tied back into the input that would limit the loop to running at 1 iteration per 6 cycles, but it seems possible to do it faster by using Peter Cordes' idea to add the carries separately (which doesn't tie the calculation together in the same way) and merge the two separate sums after the loop

Thank you for the u/v clarification. I am a quite old developer, used to write x86 assembler code 25 years ago (e.g. wrote a DOS extender - OMG, this is embarrassing... :-))

PLEASE DO CHECK Andrey's solution above. It is implemented using intrinsics, it needs only SSE2. This AVX-512 was more a 'research project' for me. You can learn more about AVX-512, K0..K7 mask registers, etc. But Andrey's statement is correct: AVX-512 does not bring any advantage into this. SSE2 is more than sufficient!
